# Nuget Restore Unable to Find .NET Core 6 SDK Libraries

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm attempting to build an ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages application while only connected to our internal nuget package store and not nuget.org. The nuget restore is throwing errors because it's failing to find .NET Core Framework libraries like `System.IO` and `System.Linq`.

My coworker is able to build this application without connecting to nuget.org and it builds on our Azure DevOps build server but it fails for me locally with 122 errors like the following.

> NU1101 - Unable to find package System.IO
> NU1101 - Unable to find package System.Linq

I have the .NET Core 6 SDK and Runtimes installed

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.203
 Commit:    5b005c19f5

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found
```

I've tried deleting the project and pulling it down from source control. I've tried cleaning up my project file. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling .NET Core and Visual Studio.

Does anyone know why nuget isn't finding my local sdk libraries and how I might fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing your nuget package sources with your coworker's.

In Visual Studio, right click the solution > Manage Nuget Packages> Click gear in top right corner. This should open a window showing your nuget package sources. It sounds like you could be missing a source that your coworker has

[image]

Comment: The whole issue here is that we both should only have our build server's local package source and not be connected to nuget.org or any other package source.

Comment: The libraries it's failing to find are listed in Dependencies -> Frameworks -> Microsoft.NETCore.App and I checked and the files are there.

Comment: Is your build server listed as a package source in the screen I posted?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's got a directory reference to the nuget package source our Azure Devops server uses for its package source.

Comment: Did you check the contents of that directory on your machine? Do you have a nuget package living there?